# React redux - 'Maximum update depth exceeded' error

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

When I want to login into my app, after entering the correct details and pressing the 'Login' button, I get this error:

[image]

The URL changes to 'dashboard' as the code suggests, but I cannot see the content of the page, but the above error.

In the console I can see that the code from the Header component (which is part of Dashboard) is accessed many times (which I suppose is causing the problem):

[image]

If I refresh the page, everything works fine. Also, if I logout and go back to the login page, I can login without errors. But if I refresh the page and I try to login, I get the error back.

Here is the code:

Header Component:

```
const Header = withRouter(({ history }) => {

const values = useSelector((state) => ({...state.sharedReducer}));
console.log('***  VALUES: ', values);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const handleMenuClick = () => dispatch(menuClickAction());
const handleLinkClick = () => dispatch(closeMenuAction());
................
```

Login Component:

```
  //  Runs only once on init
  useEffect(() => {
    if(isAuth) {
      props.history.push("dashboard"); //  Redirect to 'dashboard'
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    //  Clear the form
    dispatch(clearFormDataAction());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!values.emailEmptyError && !values.passwordEmptyError && values.email.length && values.password.length && !values.isFormValid) {
      dispatch(enableSubmitButtonAction());
        }
  }, [values, dispatch]);

  const handleSubmitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleLoading(true);

    const loginDetails = {
      email: values.email,
      password: values.password
    };

    AuthService.login(loginDetails)
      .then(response => {
        if(response) {
          LocalStorageService.setItem('currentUser', response.data.user);
          props.history.push("dashboard"); //  Redirect to 'dashboard'
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        handleSubmitError(i18n.t("ERRORS.LOGIN_WRONG_DETAILS"));
        console.log('error: ', error);
      });
   }
```

Can someone please advise what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Try wrapping `values` in `useMemo` before adding it to the dependency array in `useEffect`.

Comment: Provide the empty array `[]` as second argument to `useEffect` where you have `props.history.push("dashboard");`.

Comment: @ravibagul91 - Thanks for your suggestion. I tried that before, but I still get the error. And also, in VScode I get this error while adding an empty array: `React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'isAuth' and 'props.history'. Either include them or remove the dependency array`. If I add the two missing dependencies, I get the same error in the browser.

Comment: @Clarity - Can you please provide more details how can I do that? My case seems a little different from what I see in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: @decebal did you check your privateroute code inside your return() or render?